# Installing Wordpress in a subdirectory, getting 403 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I did a local install of Wordpress by unzipping the install files into MAMP/htdocs/subdirectory and then successfully completing the installation. 
There is a complete website in MAMP/htdocs/ (which doesn't use WordPress). When I try to access localhost:8888/subdirectory, I'm getting a 403 error. 
I found the cause which is a line in MAMP/htdocs/.htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex src/index.php
```

When I remove this line, the problem is resolved, but, of course, I need this line for the main website to function properly. Is there a workaround to get WordPress working in the subdirectory (maybe by editing the default .htaccess that was installed by WordPress in MAMP/htdocs/subdirectory/.htaccess?)

Answer (score 0):

Post your `.htaccess` code or you can try the below `.htaccess` code just the change the sub directory to the folder name

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub-directory-name
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sub-directory-name/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```